# Fetch rich cardano addresses?

Tags: cardano-cli, blockfrost, cardano-address

I am building some dapps on Cardano network.

What I want to do is to

> fetch cardano addresses whose balances are more than 1M ada.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the tag `blockfrost` so I assume that is your tool of preference.

I believe the only solution using blockfrost would be performing a series of requests for every stake address to the ["specific account" endpoint](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Accounts/paths/%7E1accounts%7E1%7Bstake_address%7D/get)and access the `controlled_amount` field.

you could get a list of all the addresses from a tool like koios: https://api.koios.rest/#get-/account_list

However, tools like blockfrost and koios are not meant for such queries;

What you are asking for is a snapshot of all possible addresses currently present on the blockchain; so what you likely want is to have your own cardano node and your own cardano-db-sync instance to perform these queries.